# Set Environment Variables From a .ps1 Script

Tags: powershell, npm

I'm currently working on a Node.js project, and would like to automate the setting of environment variables. I've written a script (`set_env.ps1`) that looks something like this:

```
Write-Host "Setting environment variables...";
$env:CLIENT_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$env:CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
[etc]
```

And I call this from some npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "install:windows": "powershell ./set_env.ps1",
  "start": "npm run install:windows && node index",
  "monitor": "npm run install:windows && nodemon index"
},
```

It doesn't seem to work though. I can enter those same commands manually, one at a time, in the command line, and environment variables are set. Just by running the script, though, "Setting environment variables..." prints to the powershell prompt, but no variables get set.

Everything on the Internet seems to want to do this from the prompt, one env var at a time. This is extremely tedious with a long list of environment variables, and the embedded Powershell prompt in Webstorm has a habit of not accepting pasted strings.

Comment: In general every spawned process inherits a copy of the parent environment which is lost when terminating the spawned process. You've to look for a different method to handover vars.

Comment: You would need to set the variables in the process that triggers your `npm` commands.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart hehh, well that's not really something you can do when running npm from the command prompt, as I'm doing... but, your comment got me thinking, and I realized: I *can* run the `npm` commands in a Powershell script. Answer forthcoming.

Comment: "that's not really something you can do when running npm from the command prompt" - (?) If you are at a command prompt, you can set the variables, then run your `npm` commands. This applies regardless of whether you're using cmd.exe or PowerShell.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Yeah you're right, I misread your comment. I've got a single process that both sets the variables and initiates the server now, so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this question because it's likely somebody else will run into this issue.

As the two comments indicated, a Powershell script process's environment is lost on termination. Therefore, environment variables set inside the script won't get passed to the Powershell prompt.

Instead of chaining npm scripts to call everything we need, instead we can call `npm run monitor` or `npm run start` from the powershell script, like so:

```
Write-Host "Setting environment variables...";
$env:CLIENT_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$env:CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
[etc]
[...]
Write-Host "Initializing process..."

npm run monitor
```

Then, we have our npm scripts like so:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:windows": "powershell ./start.ps1",
  "start": "node index",
  "monitor": "nodemon index"
}
```

To initiate, run `npm run start:windows` from the command prompt.

Comment: If someone is here and wants to add environment variables to their current shell, the command is `cat .\env.sh | Invoke-Expression`...one liner, very simple

Where `env.sh` is the name of the file that sets your environment variables, although, this could do anything